# .exe python script created with Pyinstaller doesnt create text files

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a simple script that reads in data from an excel file from within the same directory, does some analysis, and then creates 4 text files holding this analysis. The script works perfectly when run from the command line, but doesn't work when running from an exe created with Pyinstaller

The command I run to create the exe:

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

I have done nothing fancy in regards to file placement, the script expects the file it needs to be in the same directory, and I expect the text files to show up in the same directory

In the command line window that shows up, it does show the correct results because I have also printed them in the script.

I have used `pandas` and `itertools` within the script if that helps

EDIT:
It works without the `--onefile` option, but it would be best if it was just one file